# Обработка нажатия enter на клавиатуре Android в браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно повесить обработчик события, когда пользователь нажал enter в поле ввода в браузере. Keypress на андройде не работает, keyup возвращает всегда один и тот же код 229 и при этом не срабатывает на enter, а только на символах. Нужно это для того, чтобы при нажатии enter от одного инпута плавно скроллилось до следующего инпута с помощью animate scrollTop

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно? Спрашиваю, потому что есть вероятность, что вашу задачу нужно решить другим способом

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Насколько я знаю в хроме на андроид такой функционал работает *из коробки*. Нажимаешь на enter, Он переходит к следующему инпуту или сабмитит форму.

Comment: Из коробки переход будет резким, а мне нужно, чтобы был плавным. Пример можно посмотреть на этом сайте https://byjakt.com/contact/ в мобильной версии. Насколько я понял, там сначала убирается клавиатура, потом скроллится и снова появляется

Comment: Скиньте, пожалуйста, код вашей реализации